# watchOS vs iOS and Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

In Xcode I am having issues between watchOS and iOS.  The following code is the same for both targets:

watchOS

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {
    var variable1: Float?
}
```

iOS

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var variable1: Float?
}
```

the class

```
class SomeClass: ObservableObject {
    
    #if os(iOS)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    #elseif os(watchOS)
    let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as! WKExtension
    #endif

func somefunc(){
delegate.variable1 = 0.0 // Fine when target is iOS, fails when watchOS with WKExtension has no member variable1
   }
}
```

I am not sure why that delegate.variable1 is invalid for watchOS but not iOS

Comment: `WKExtension` is the extension base class. You want `as! ExtensionDelegate`  That forced downcast should give you a warning that it will fail and should crash at runtime

Comment: Thanks.. I am now getting a nil in the Initializer of SomeClass at the line of let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate

Comment: Per @paulw11 this was a simple update... so closing the question.